# Azure SQL Server Bulk Insert TCP Provider Problem

Tags: python, sql-server, database, azure, database-administration

I use SQL Server on Azure and I make a bulk insert with Python but I  constantly get error.  How can I solve the problem?

Error : TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Best,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/apps-forcibly-closed-tls-connection-errors), this error message returned when the secure TLS handshake is negotiated between the client and the server by using TLS_DHE cipher suite.

To fix this issue, make sure that both the client and server involved in a connection are running Windows that have the leading zero fixes for TLS_DHE installed. It's recommended to install the updates since they enhance the conformance to TLS_DHE specifications.

If you can't update the windows, a [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/apps-forcibly-closed-tls-connection-errors#workaround) is available here.